# How to access session variable to display img_path in img tag in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4 version

I have set an image path in session of laravel in controller in the `img_url` variable

This is the html code how i am trying to access the image

```
<img alt="" class="img-circle" src="{{ URL::asset('session("img_url")') }}" />
```

The `img_url` has the path `assets/user_images/default.png` in the public folder

It giving me an error in console like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)  session(%22img_url%22)
```

Comment: remove quotes inside `asset()` function `{{ URL::asset(session("img_url")) }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in quotation marks 'session("img_url")'

```
<img alt="" class="img-circle" src="{{ URL::asset(session("img_url")) }}" />
```

or

```
<img alt="" class="img-circle" src="{{ asset(session("img_url")) }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change to

```
<img alt="" class="img-circle" src="{{ URL::asset(session('img_url')) }}" />
```

Because session("img_url") in '' is string not function.

Answer (score 1):

Here session("img_url") is placed inside single quotes. You can use concatenation as below

```
<img alt="" class="img-circle" src="{{ URL::asset("'".session("img_url")."'") }}" />
```